# How to display certain parts of two fields from another file in an awk script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, files, scripting

I have the following file called `calories`:

```
Apple pie s s n
Lemon pie s n n 
Orange pie s s s
```

And I have this awk script that prints the pie with the maximum times that s(sugar) appears.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ sugar=0}
{
$1=""
count[++cnt] = gsub("s","")
$0 = ""
for(i=1; i<=cnt;i++){
     $i=count[i]
     if(count[i]>sugar)
          sugar=count[i]
}
}
END{
print $1" "$2" has the largest amount of sugar with" sugar" sugars"
}
```

The output I get:

`2 1 has the largest amount of sugar with 3 sugars`

Desired output:

`Orange pie has the largest amount of sugar with 3 sugars`

The command I use to run the awk script:

`awk -f script.awk calories`

Comment: Is the first field always a single word. Are the fields delimited by a space? Do you always have exactly three single-letter fields at the end? Might there be other words than `pie` in the second field, and how should these be treated?

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk and relying on the field separator set to the sugar `s` pattern:

```
awk -F'\\<s\\>' '
     sugar<NF{sugar=NF;pie=$1}
     END{print pie "has the largest amount of sugar with " sugar-1 " sugar"}
' file
```

The only statement is to set the variable `sugar` with number of `s` found in the line, and set pie name.

When the file is parsed, the `END` statement is executed and prints the wanted string.

Comment: Thank you for responding but it won't work for my script it still displays the old output :(

Comment: Try a `Mars bar`...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the counts in an array and iterate over it for each new value - just store the current max and its corresponding pie:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  sugar_max = 0;
  pie_max = "";
}
{
  pie = $1; 
  $1 = ""; sugar = gsub("s","");
  if (sugar > sugar_max) {
    sugar_max = sugar;
    pie_max = pie;
  }
}

END {
  printf "%s pie has the largest amount of sugar with %d sugars\n", pie_max, sugar_max;
}
```

The `BEGIN` block isn't strictly necessary in this case, since awk variables are implicitly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
awk '
function SCNT(FLD) { x = $FLD; return gsub (/s/, "&", $FLD)}
SMX < SC = SCNT(0) - SCNT(1) - SCNT(2)  {SMX = SC
                     LN = $0
                    }
END {print "Largest sugar count of", SMX, "in", LN
    }
' file
Largest sugar count of 3 in Orange pie s s s
```